# DolphinDB random sample functions

Tags: function, random, sample, dolphindb

Can I sample an array a = [1, 2, 3, 4] based on the specified probabilities p = [0.1, 0.1, 0.3, 0.5]?
For example, in python I can use `np.random.choice(a=[1, 2, 3, 4], size=100, p=[0.1, 0.1, 0.3, 0.5])`

Answer (score 0):

For me I will form a new random choice data list by percentages/probabilities, for example do random choice on `[1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4]` will be equivalent with your data and probabilities.

You can use `take` (https://www.dolphindb.com/help/FunctionsandCommands/FunctionReferences/t/take.html) function for helping the data forming:

```
v = take(1, 1) <- take(2, 1) <- take(3, 3) <- take(4, 5)
rand(v, 100)
```

Comment: It would be helpful for others if you could add more information about how and why, such as adding an explanation about `take` and linking to relevant documentation.